# Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of A. Prove that rank($\lambda I - A$) = rank(($\lambda I - A)^2$).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of A. Prove that rank($\lambda I - A$) = rank(($\lambda I - A)^2$).

The hint they provided is that for any invertible matrix B, rank(AB) = rank (A) and rank(BA) = rank(A).

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Maybe you can first try it when $A$ is actually a diagonal matrix.

Comment: I've tried letting B = $\lambda I - A$, then using the hint form rank B = rank $B^2$. But i know that B might not be invertible so the hint cannot be used so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable there is a matrix $U$, with $U U^{-1}=Id$ such that $D=U^{-1}A U$, or $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D=diag(\lambda,\lambda_1,...\lambda_{d-1})$ is diagoanal and $\lambda_i =$eigenvalues of A ($\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ if $i \neq j$) then $rank(\lambda Id-A)=rank(\lambda Id-UDU^{-1})=rank(U(\lambda Id - D)U^{-1})=rank(\lambda Id-D)$, where I used your hint twice. Then I can see that $D-\lambda Id=diag(0,\lambda_1-\lambda,...\lambda_{d-1}-\lambda) $ and $(D-\lambda Id)^2=diag(0,(\lambda_1-\lambda)^2,...(\lambda_{d-1}-\lambda)^2) $. I think that should help you, be careful, in my computation I assumed that the eigenspaces of every $\lambda_i$ is onedimensional!

Comment: You are assuming that $A$ can be **orthogonally** diagonalized (which would imply that $A$ is symmetric).

Comment: Of course, I made a mistake, you are right. I edited my post!

Comment: Thank you! This allowed me to solve the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows: note that the image of $A - \lambda I$ is spanned by eigenvectors of $A$ that do *not* correspond to $\lambda$.  Thus, $\ker(A - \lambda I) \cap \operatorname{im}(A - \lambda I) = \{0\}$.  Conclude that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A - \lambda I)^2 = \dim [(A - \lambda I)^2(\Bbb C^n)]  
\\= \dim[\operatorname{im}[(A - \lambda I)|_{\operatorname{im}(A - \lambda I)}]]
\\= \dim\operatorname{im}(A - \lambda I)
\\ = \operatorname{rank}(A - \lambda I)
$$
as desired.

---

A method that uses the actual hint: suppose that we have $S \Lambda S^{-1}$, where $S$ is invertible and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with
$$
\Lambda = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 I_{m_1} \\ & \lambda_2 I_{m_2}\\ && \ddots \\ &&& \lambda_k I_{m_k}}
$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are distinct and $\lambda_1 = \lambda$. Let $B = SMS^{-1}$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{I_{m_1} \\ & (\lambda_2 - \lambda) I_{m_2}\\ && \ddots \\ &&& (\lambda_k- \lambda) I_{m_k}}.
$$
Verify that $B$ is invertible and that $B(A - \lambda I) = (A - \lambda I)^2$.