# Diagonalization and rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-rank

I have been stuck on this problem for a really long time and it is due in a few hours.

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix and $λ$ an eigenvalue of $A$. Prove that $$rank(λI - A) = rank((λI - A)^2)$$

*Hint 1*: For any invertible matrix $B$, $rank(AB) = rank(BA) = rank(A)$.

*Hint 2*: Diagonalize $λI - A$ and $(λI - A)^2$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Various people have pointed out that a similar thread was opened just recently. I went over and could only partially follow one of the suggested solutions - the others were beyond my level of understanding.

In particular, this is the solution:

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, A can be written in the form $A=PDP^{-1}$, then $rank(λI − A) = rank(λI−PDP^{−1}) = rank(P(λI − D)P^{−1}) = rank(λI − D)$.

The person who suggested this solution also said that he made use of *Hint 1* twice. Here is where I am lost. I understand that $rank(λI − A) = rank(λI − PDP^{−1})$, but how does $rank(λI − PDP^{−1}) = rank(P(λI − D)P^{−1}) = rank(λI − D)$? I do not even know how he made use of *Hint 1* ):

I apologise in advance to anyone who can take the trouble to explain this solution to me, if it is supposed to be trivial!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3409771/81360)

Comment: Try computing the ranks of  $S(\lambda I - A)S^{-1}$ and $S(\lambda I - A)^2S^{-1}$, where $S$ is a matrix that diagonalizes $A$. Note that conjugating by $S$ is an isomorphism, so it doesn't change the rank.

Comment: @Bungo What is isomorphism? My Linear Algebra course does not cover that ):

Comment: @EthanLeong OK, to say it another way, $M$ and $SMS^{-1}$ are matrix representations of the same linear operator, so they have the same rank.

Comment: @Bungo I see, but why would a matrix that diagonalizes $A$ also diagonalize $(λI−A)$ and $(λI−A)^{2}$?

Comment: If you had provided context for the problem by letting us know what you tried, we would have been able to figure out which tools you have at your disposal, and would therefore have been able to write a proof that avoids using ideas that you're not familiar with (for instance, "isomorphism" and transformations over abstract vector spaces)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah. Yes, I should have done that. Sorry.

Comment: @EthanMark Have you tried multiplying $S(\lambda I - A)S^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your edit: note that
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(\lambda I−PDP^{−1})&=
\operatorname{rank}(P(\lambda I)P^{-1} − PDP^{−1})
\\ &= \operatorname{rank}(P[(\lambda I)P^{-1} − DP^{−1}])
\\ &= \operatorname{rank}(P[(\lambda I) − D]P^{−1})
\\ &= \operatorname{rank}(P[(\lambda I − D)P^{−1}])
=\operatorname{rank}((\lambda I − D)P^{−1})
 = \operatorname{rank}(\lambda I − D).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh! I understand the proof completely now! I would just like to ask one more thing, which builds upon what @Bungo has suggested. If, say, $P$ diagonalizes $A$, why would the same $P$ diagonalize $(λI−A)$ and $(λI−A)^{2}$ as well? I know that $(λI−A)$ and $(λI−A)^{2}$ are both diagonalizable, but the claim would mean that $(λI−A)$ and $(λI−A)^{2}$ have the same eigenvectors (and eigenvalues) as $A$ right? How can I prove this?

Comment: @EthanMark Prove that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $(\lambda I - A)$, then it is also an eigenvector of $(\lambda I - A)^2$.

Comment: I can now see this. But I also have to prove that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then it is also an eigenvector of $(λI−A)$ right? Since $P$ diagonalizes both $A$ and $(λI−A)$?

Comment: @EthanMark If that's a new fact to you then I suppose you should.